# PHPExcel file "corrupt" when Unicode in data

Tags: unicode, phpexcel

I've been using PHPExcel successfully for months now.  Now I have users that are entering Unicode into their data, and now their reports are not opening in Excel.

The exact error that Excel 2010 gives is:
Excel found unreadable content in 'blahblahblah.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

Clicking Yes...
The file is corrupt and cannot be opened.

When I view the files (turn to .zip and open the .xml contents), I can see that everything is properly formatted.  The UTF-8 characters show up in my text editor (an accented "o" shows up as xC3 as a single item), but those encodings seem to kill Excel.

I've noticed that Unicode is used in both the cells and the sheet names.

Comment: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ "There seems to be a problem with character encoding...
It is necessary to use UTF-8 encoding for all texts in PHPExcel. If the script uses different encoding then it is possible to convert the texts with PHP's iconv() function."

Comment: `xC3` implies a single 0xC3 byte, which is not a valid UTF-8 sequence. This would make the whole file unreadable to XML parsers (eg try to load it into a web browser and you're probably get an error). You need to ensure all your strings are UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I'm going to use (though not perfect):

```
  function PHPExcel_UnicodeFix($value) {

    //data seems to be UTF-8, despite internal encoding
    // $iconv = iconv_get_encoding();
    // $it = $iconv['internal_encoding'];
    //such that $it == 'ISO-8859-1'

    //but iconv($it,"ASCII//TRANSLIT",$value) doesn't work (data is already UTF-8?)

    //Excel does not accept UTF-8?
    $value_fixed = iconv("UTF-8","ASCII//TRANSLIT",$value);

    return $value_fixed;
  }
```

I tried many combinations of iconv() before I found this to work.  I too thought UTF-8 was valid for PHPExcel, but it wasn't working.  This conversion isn't perfect, but it is readable.

Comment: So, it appears what happened is the module that wrote the UTF-8 characters was doing so despite the 'internal_encoding' settings.  So, since that module ignored the encoding, all of the internal functionality and encoders become broken.  I _should_ call the iconv_set_encoding before _that_ module runs, to ensure that the UTF-8 it writes isn't in violation of the 'internal_encoding'.